# Sequelize query of Sum aggregate functions in Node js

Tags: mysql, node.js, express, sequelize.js

I am actually trying to get all the active and inactive users in one query using this query

```
SELECT SUM(CASE WHEN users.status = 1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS 'Active_players', SUM(CASE WHEN users.status = 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS `InActive_players` FROM `users` AS `users` INNER JOIN `organization_entries` AS `organizationEntries` ON `users`.`id` = `organizationEntries`.`user_id` AND `organizationEntries`.`organization_id` = '1' AND `organizationEntries`.`type` = '001';
```

but I am not able to understand how to write this query using Sequelize query.

I have tried this link http://docs.sequelizejs.com/manual/tutorial/querying.html but could not understand properly how to implement it using sequelize.

Comment: Why not just count all users where `status` is `1` for active players and `0` for inactive players

Comment: Yes I have tried that approach and it is giving correct output also but the thing is I have many types like active, inactive,  new user , old user so I do not want to query database again and again.

Comment: Why don't you get all users and then filter them based on their status?

Comment: yes this way it could be possible but suppose there are 500 users so trying to fetch all users and then filtering them on the basis of status will take time according to me what do you think ?